# Exclude jQuery from vendor.js in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is it possible to exclude jQuery dependency from vendor.js in ember-cli when building for production only? I want to include it separately in my site.

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  I'm curious why you would want to do this.

Comment: Yes of course. I want to embed an ember app into an existing site where jQuery lib already included. So i would like to reduce vendor.js file size and also be protected from any conflicts (if there are ones!?).

Comment: Ah ok, I see.  I've got an idea that may work.  Trying it out, will post it if its successful.

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to figure it out.  I was trying to remove it using a broccoli plugin - https://github.com/rwjblue/broccoli-file-remover - but wasn't able to get it working so far.  I'll take a closer look once I'm off work.

Comment: Just remove it from your `bower.json` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the only thing worked for me was this:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
 vendorFiles: {
    production: false,
    development: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
  }
});
```

This will exclude it in production but not in development.

Answer (score 13):

You can control which files will be used in development or production using a hash like configuration. In your case you should use:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  vendorFiles: {
    'jquery.js': {
      development: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      production: false
    }
  }
});
```

Refer to [Customizing a built-in asset](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#customizing-a-built-in-asset) section for further info.

Answer (score -1):

This is a rather simple matter, check the `bower.json` file in your directory and remove the jquery entry, or simply run `bower uninstall jquery --save` in the cli.

Oups missed the in production only, well you can save it as a dev-dependency that way it's not included in the build.
So remove jquery and then run `bower install --save-dev jquery`

Comment: It make sense but it doesn't seems to work. I've put jQuery under devDependencies and after running `ember build --environment="production"` , i still have jQuery inside dist/assets/vendor.js.

Comment: Hmm let me try it out, will get back to you shortly.